# Function as argument, access inner parameter

Tags: go, function-literal, fasthttp

The package [valyala/fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/master/server.go#L127) implements the following function type:

```
type RequestHandler func(ctx *RequestCtx)
```

It is used in [buaazp/fasthttprouter](https://github.com/buaazp/fasthttprouter/blob/master/router.go#L195) like this:

```
func (r *Router) Handle(method, path string, handle fasthttp.RequestHandler) {
    //...
}
```

I am trying to wrap these like this (open for suggestions on implementation):

```
//myapp/router

type Request struct {
    fasthttp.RequestCtx
}

type RequestHandler func(*Request)

func Handle(method string, path string, handler RequestHandler) {
    //I need to access the fasthttp.RequestCtx stuff in here...
}
```

How can I achieve this? Or, if this is not the way to go at all, how can I achieve my goal as mentioned below for a router package?

---

**BACKGROUND**

**Goal**: My wish is to wrap tooling packages (sessions, database, routing, etc.) in order to make my app agnostic to the implementation of these packages. I wish to do this primarily for the purpose of being able to extend these with domain-specific functionality, and being able to switch one 3rd party lib for another, if I ever would need to do so. It also makes debugging and logging easier.

**Method**: I create native types and functions, which map to the functionality of the imported packages.

**Problem**: I am stuck on how to wrap a foreign (i.e. imported) *function type* properly.

Answer (score 0):

At all your idea looks very good. Some things you could change:

```
//myapp/router    

// Using a composition is idiomatic go code 
// this should work. It can't get better.
type Request struct {
    fasthttp.RequestCtx
}

// I would make the RequestHandler as a real Handler. In go it would be
// a interface
type RequestHandler interface{
   Request(*Request)
}
// If you have a function, which needs to access parameters from `Request`
// you should take this as an input.
func Handle(method string, path string, req *Request) {
    //Access Request via req.Request ...
}
```

Because if you pass a function or an interface into your function, which needs also `Request` as input the caller needs to create that before he calls your Handle function. Why not change that function just for the input you really need?

Comment: I passed in the functions as arguments to mimic the implementation of the packages. In net/http, its `func Route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}`, in buaazp/fasthttprouter it's `func Route(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {}`. If I leave out the function types, how should I declare a route under this implementation?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you. So you want to use the fasthttp as server and combine this with fasthttprouter for the routes. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, however invisible to the rest of the application. I would like to wrap all of the 3rd party imports into _myapp/router_, so that other packages only import _myapp/router_ and nothing else. My problem lies within declaring routes, as they are formatted as _handlerFunctions_ with signature types from the imported packages. This means they are usually formatted as in my previous comment. Ideally, I'd like to be able to declare a route as `router.GET(path string, ctx router.Context){}` or `router.GET(path string, func(ctx router.Context) {})`, and map these to fasthttprouter implementation...

Comment: If you want to write some middleware, which wraps the handler, the handle function has to return also a handler. Look here: https://medium.com/@matryer/the-http-handler-wrapper-technique-in-golang-updated-bc7fbcffa702#.hetv7iibf

Comment: Thank you for that link! I was able to wrap the router package, however it still relies on a `func Route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}` type of implementation. I guess it's as good as it's gonna get for now.